# How to separate web videos from Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, flash-player

What I want is to fill web videos to the full window without the tabs, address bar(even all the window decorations) so that I can see more area of videos when the window holds 1/4 of the screen.

Are there any extentions that can do this?

Or what should I know to write a program by myself?

Answer (score 0):

This extension should do what you want:
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/popout-video-player/nlkkdjbboeginjddlaldghockncacjpm

> Play any video from YouTube, Dailymotion, Vimeo, Twitch or Rutube in a standalone, full resizable window!
>   Just click the extension button to open a YouTube, Dailymotion, Vimeo, Twitch or Rutube video in a resizable window.